# Calculating similarities between all IDs and associates string/sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have a dataframe, which consists of two columns as shown below. I want to compute Smith Water Similarity between all these sequences using the function defined below.

Comment: Please add the dataframe